# How to Test security of the android mobile application?

Tags: mobile, security-testing

I am new to testing the security of applications.

I know basic security like invalid credentials, but I don't know much about security testing for mobile app.

Please tell me what all can I try to do a security test of a mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

There are some nice points that you can cover with a cheat-sheet from the guys over at OWASP.

My suggestion is that you should try to go point-by-point in the list [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Android_Testing_Cheat_Sheet)

Long story short for android applications is the following:

- Get the APK file.
- Decompile the APK file
- Install the APK.
- Intercept the requests.
- Check for local storage

There are already a lot of tools in this App-Use, namely apktool, smali, baksmali, manifest explorer, jdgui, dex2jar, Android SDK, adb, burp suite, etc

Answer (score 2):

To get started, may be you should refer the [OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide repository](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg) on Github.

It has tons of information, including what you should test, and how you should test, including information of tools which are used to test that particular scenario. It is a very active repository, with lots of activity happening everyday (Please star so that you can receive notifications).

The best part is that they start with the very basics - the architecture of both IOS and Android operating system and then build it from there.

Combined with the cheat sheet given in the other answer, you have a goldmine of scenarios for mobile security testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run static code analysis on the app.

This will give a detailed report on the possible security issues with your app.

There are some tools available which will help you to do so.

Infact I have designed a web application which runs this analysis on .apk or .ipa file which a user uploads and displays the result of the scan in HTML format.

Feel free to explore https://thesecurityscan.com/